# Selenium: Force testers to choose between specific values for argument

Tags: java, selenium

This might be a completely stupid question but is it at all possible in either Java or Selenium to force testers to use a specific string or value for a method argument?

I am writing a Selenium framework that the testers will use to write tests. They don't see the Selenium code.

I have a method in the framework called `setCustomerType` that selects a radio button from 4 valid values in the GUI: `Phone, Store, Online, Home`. I want the tester in their test to not have the option of entering these as string arguments but rather to choose from a predefined set of values somehow. This is how it currently looks:

SetCustomerDetails.java

```
public void setCustomerType(String salesType){
        WebElement salesTypeOption = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=" + salesType + "][name='salesType']"));
        fixedTypeOptions.click();
    }
```

SetCustomerTypeTest.java

```
@Test
public void setCustomerType() {
    SetCustomerDetails customerDetails = new SetCustomerDetails();
    customerDetails.setCustomerType("Online");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an enum. That could look something like this:

```
public enum CustomerType {
    Phone("Phone"), Store("Store"), Online("Online"), Home("Home");

    private String id;

    public CustomerType(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then your setter could look like this:

```
public void setCustomerType(CustomerType salesType){
    WebElement salesTypeOption = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=" + salesType.getId() + "][name='salesType']"));
    fixedTypeOptions.click();
}
```